# C++ Can I assign an int by using string::at?

Tags: c++, string, int, variable-assignment

In my code I have this:

```
int enemyNumber = numberType.at(0);
```

`numberType` is a string.

The first character in `string numberType` is '1'. But `int enemyNumber` instead becomes 48 after that assignment.

What is going on and how do I get enemyNumber to become '1'?

Comment: I hope you weren't planning on having more than 9 enemies.

Comment: Haha, I foresaw that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because 48 is the character code of `1`. To get the integer value instead, deduce `'0'` that is write something like: `int enemyNumber = numberType.at(0) - '0';`. In this way you will get the character code of `'1'` minus the character code of `'0'` which is namely `1`. This will work for all digits as their character codes are consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 7):

To convert a single character, with a value from `'0'` to `'9'`, to the corresponding number, subtract the value of `'0'`:

```
int enemyNumber = numberType.at(0) - '0';
```

If you wanted to convert a string containing multiple digits, the standard library can help:

```
// C++11 or later
int n = std::stoi(s);

// Historically
int n = std::atoi(s.c_str());  // no error checking

std::istringstream ss(s);
if (ss >> n) {
     // success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay within string objects, you can do the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string numberType("1234");
    const int enemyNumber = std::stoi( numberType.substr(0,1) );

    std::cout << enemyNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

stoi() will do the conversion from string to int for you.

Comment: as you can see, there are so many ways to do very similar things, so in the end, your solution depends on personal taste.